# XSD schema for xml with same name but different type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

How can a build a xsd declaring all elements for this XML:

```
<a>
  <myElement type="type1">
    <idElement>1</idElement>
    <TypeOneContent>my content</TypeOneContent>
  </myElement>
  <myElement type="type2">
    <idElement>2</idElement>
    <qteElemetType2>3</qteElemetType2>
  </myElement>
  <myElement type="type3">
    <idElement>3</idElement>
  </myElement>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the XSD for your XML

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="a">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="myElement" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="idElement"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="TypeOneContent" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="qteElemetType2" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type" use="optional"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thak you. Orignially my xml is a huge file with a lots of different types. So is there a way to have a complexType for each type and not to declare all in the same?

Answer (score 0):

The constraint "Element declarations consistent" which is present in both XSD 1.0 and XSD 1.1 says that if two sibling elements have the same name, then they must have the same type. So the answer to your question is that it can't be done.